# Change major tick marks on survival curve using autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I am creating survival curves and plotting them with `autoplot`, which uses `ggplot2`. Censoring is done in months but I want the x axis to be labeled in years and the tick marks to be in years.

How can I do this?

I have used the following code to generate the image below:

```
surv.first <- survfit(Surv(first$time,first$censor) ~ strata(first$Histo), data=first)
autoplot(surv.first, conf.int = FALSE, censor=FALSE)
```

This is the curve I am currently getting, but want the x axis tick marks to be years 1-5:[image]